# Javascript - Obtaining length of input keydown

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox and for what I'm seeing using console.log everytime I press a key an event is fired with this format:

```
keydown { target: <input#WebCombo_input.ig_82235515_r28.text>, key: "s", charCode: 0, keyCode: 83 }
```

If I clic over the input part in Firefox's console I can see it's properties, and between them is textLength which is what I need.

So my question is, How can I get that length into a variable?

Comment: so you want the length of the text in your textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `event.target.value.length` (JavaScript) or `event.target.val().length` (jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Simple and precise way is to get the `target` element **value** since it's an **input** for non input you access the `innerHTML` instead, check the code snippet below

```js
var input = document.getElementById("field");
var variable  = "";

function showVariable(length){
variable = length; //here you can manipulate the value
  document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = variable;
}
```

```html
<p>
<input onkeydown="showVariable(this.value.length)" id="field" type="text" placeholder="Please type something">
</p>

Value: <span id="show"></span>
```